# Second client's canvas not registering input? Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, networking, canvas, multiplayer

Obligatory "i'm very new". I couldn't figure out how to hook up a canvas that the player interacts with (chooses which team they'll be playing on in the game) that I had would work out if it was in the scene that the player prefab would be spawned into. So I put the canvas into the prefab with the player and set it as inactive once they select which team.

It works flawlessly for the host client (changes their "playerTeam" int and spawns them where they should be spawned) but when the second client joins their canvas is there, but won't take any input. I know it's this because the debug.log i put in right after input is not being run. here are the code segments that are necessary.

i have the canvas disabled by default and activated after an (isLocalPlayer) run on a script on the parent object.  I can't add a networkID to the canvas because the prefab parent object has the networkID and they both can't have one, which means I cannot use (isLocalPlayer) on the canvas script, which may be the issue.  But I also can't have the canvas on the actual level screen because even if i find the game object of the canvas, i don't know how to make it find which player to assign the playerTeam int to.

The following is run on a script attached to the canvas (of which the empty player object is the parent of)

```
Button CT = chooseCT.GetComponent<Button>();

CT.onClick.AddListener(parent.GetComponent<Sync>().CmdpickedCT);
```

and this is the code that runs on a script on the parent object

```
[Command]
public void CmdpickedCT()
{
   GetComponent<Movement>().playerTeam = 2;
   teamSelector.SetActive(false);
}
```

I apologize if I'm missing something big here. Thanks for any help.

for more information i have more stuff in the movement script run once the playerTeam is set to something other than 0, this also works on the host. Any other information you can give about how to pass info from the objects in the game scene to the instantiated objects would be great too. Thanks again.

Additional information, it seems like if i have both the second client and first client on the canvas at the same time, I cannot choose my team with either. It says "Trying to send command for object without authority".

Comment: Could you explain what went wrong when you tried to use one canvas in your hierarchy? I don't see the need for putting a canvas inside each prefab.

Comment: Well the game starts on one scene which is supposed to be a gamefinder of sorts and then it switches to a scene with the actual level.  In the scene I didn't know how to change the player info (playerTeam) from the canvas in the scene.  If i did a script on a canvas in the level how would it know what player to change the variable on?  I tried this and used (isLocalPlayer) and nothing would happen.  Basically I am having trouble with transferring data from objects in the game level to the prefab that isn't instantiated until the game starts mostly because of confusion between players.

Comment: Also if it's on the scene it tells me that I don't have authority for that object.